# Android CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

```
public static String getRealPath(Uri uri, Context context) {
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    String[] filePath = file.getPath().split(":");
    String fileId = filePath[filePath.length - 1];
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", 
            new String[]{fileId},  
            null); 

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        String realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
        cursor.close();
        return realPath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

this is My code ( uri to path )
When bringing up an image, it brings the absolute path well. But when I call the file, I can't call it.

When i called file Like this..

```
    Intent fileChoose = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    fileChoose.setType("*/*");
    fileChoose.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    fileLauncher.launch(fileChoose);
```

and Receive Like this..

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> fileLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getData() != null) {
                File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(CommFunc.getRealPath(result.getData().getData(), FileChooserActivity.this)));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and i called Image Like this..

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
setResult(RESULT_OK, galleryIntent);
galleryLauncher.launch(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"));
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: `getRealPath` is never, ever the right approach. You have a `Uri`, that is the one and only way to access that content.

Comment: If so, please tell me how to know the absolute path through uri.
Like this(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Study_BitmapEncrypt/image/ORIGINAL_FILE_202202111633.png)

Comment: I have a READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE /WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permissions